# how can i update cloned repository's dependencies

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mern-stack-client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @testing-library/react@9.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^14.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @testing-library/react@"^14.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@14.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^14.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-06T15_33_44_892Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-06T15_33_44_892Z-debug-0.log

it should not show these many errors , even after using npm update many times